# Windows Server 2008 R2 - Remote Desktop : how to allow user copy from client to server but prevent server to client?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, file-transfer

I have windows server 2008R2. I & friends are using remote desktop for connecting to server.

My problem is : I want to prevent user copy anything from server to client (or at least, file & folder) but still allow them copy from client to server.

How can I do that? I use google but there are no answer :(

Thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't half-enable it - if you enable clipboard on the server-side, then anyone who log in (and, of course, enable it in the client) can use it both to copy from and to the server.

You should look for some other remoting solution.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense. Even if the feature exists in the protocol there is nothing preventing a client or server implementation from having a setting to disable the feature - or just not implement it at all.

Comment: @kasperd Of course the server or the client can ignore parts of the data, but the default tools (meaning RDP server and RDP client) either allow clipboard or the don't - you can't take half. So unless he is going to code a new server-side RDP it's not possible to control what the end-users do with this feature. But maybe I wasn't clear enough and should rephrase my answer.